# regular expression search in VS not working

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am using this regular expression to try and find any line in my code that has a double comment slash followed by any amount of whitespace and then a hash. so..

```
//       #endif
```

for example.

I am using `////*[ ]/#` but it's not finding anything. What am I doing wrong?

As far as I was aware this (`////` is looking for the double slash and `*[ ]/#` is looking for any number of whitespace followed by the slash. I'm sure I'm getting something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to double the forward slashes (they do not need to be escaped). Backslashes are the escape sequence and they do need escaping.

You are also using `*` just after `/` meaning any number of `/`, not any number of spaces.

Try the following (any number of *spaces* between that `//` and `#`):

```
// *\#
```

For reference - [Visual Studio regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).

The Visual Studio regular expression engine doeshave a character escape for unicode whitespace - `:Wh` so it may be closer to what you wanted:

```
//:Wh*\#
```

You can also construct your own character class containing additional whitespace characters if wanted (say, vertical tab, line breaks etc...), but that may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Try `//:b*:Po` in Find (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). It will catch what you want. I hope it helps.